# Highcharts Flag series tooltip does not follow yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I refer to http://jsfiddle.net/VJsjg/2/

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            marginTop: 100, //avoid overlapping with navigator
            spacingLeft: 0
        },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        top: 40
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    yAxis:[{
        top:140,
        height:150
    }],
    series: [{
        id:'msft',
        name: 'MSFT',            
        data: MSFT
    }]
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.addAxis({
        id:'secondY',            
        top:300,
        height:150
    });

    chart.addSeries({
        id:'adbe',
        yAxis:'secondY',
        name: 'ADBE', 
        data: ADBE
    });
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    chart.addSeries(
    // the event marker flags
        {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'G',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bulls Clear Path to 1.50 Figure'
            }],
            onSeries : 'adbe',
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        });



   });
});
```

Notice that the circlepin H  and C are at the correct position of the bottom series. However, when we do a mouseover, the position of the tooltip followed the top series instead.

Has anyone encountered the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by adding a

```
tooltip: {
   followPointer:true
}
```

to the series.

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/VGj9q/ for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip can follow yAxis by adding followingPointer:true, but in this way, the tooltip shape became 'square', not 'callout'.

I think this is a bug of highcharts, some similar issues can be found on github. But seems they didn't fix it for 'flag' series.

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/4jt9jxs1/2/ for this issue.

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
   height: 600,
  },

 navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: [{
    id: "1",
    height: 200,
    },{
    id: "2",
    top: 300,
    height: 200,
    }],
    tooltip:{
      shared: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        id: 'dataseries',
        data: usdeur,
        yAxis: "1"
    },{
        name: 'USD to EUR1',
        id: 's1',
        data: usdeur,
        yAxis:"2"
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
            title: 'A',
            text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
            title: 'A',
            text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        shape: 'squarepin',
        width: 16
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1),
            text: 'Shape: "circlepin"'
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2010, 9, 1),
            text: 'Shape: "circlepin"'
        }],
        shape: 'circlepin',
        onSeries: 's1',
        yAxis:"2",
        title: 'B',
        tooltip: {
         followPointer: true,
        },
        width: 16
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2012, 2, 10),
            title: 'C',
            text: 'Shape: "flag"'
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 11),
            title: 'C',
            text: 'Shape: "flag"'
        }],
        yAxis:"2",
        color: '#5F86B3',
        fillColor: '#5F86B3',
        onSeries: 's1',
        width: 16,
        style: { // text style
            color: 'white'
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                fillColor: '#395C84' // darker
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```